# Can variables be used in import statements for Sass files?

Tags: import, sass

In Less I can do something like this

```
@basePath:"../../some_crazy_project_path_to_repeat/less/";
@import "@{basePath}less.less";
```

So I tried to do the same thing in Sass

```
$basePath:"../../some_crazy_project_path_to_repeat/less/";
@import "${basePath}less.scss";
// Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: ${basePath}less.scss.
```

and

```
@import "#{basePath}less.scss";
// Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: #{basePath}less.scss.
```

Is there a way to do this in Sass?

Comment: [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) uses `#{}`

Comment: @steveax interpolation is a really cool feature, but i can't wrap my head around how it would help in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried `@import "#{basePath}less.scss"`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Import a Sass file so you can use variables/mixins defined in it, or create a CSS import statement?

Comment: @steveax thanks. Im importing a bunch of component definitions from a third party library. I can repeat the full path n-times, but I had figured if there was a way to accomplish this in Less, why not Sass? @ Arman H, I added your note to the question. I think Andrey knows something I don't :)

Comment: Andrey's answer is correct, you cannot use string interpolation for Sass imports.

Comment: @steveax Your answer solved my problem instantly, thank you.

Comment: Use `@import "#{$basePath}less.scss";` and you're free to go

Comment: @BernaMariano, `@import "#{$basePath}less.scss";` causes an Sass error. It won't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use conditional stuff for imports in SASS.

Consider creating a [Compass](https://github.com/Snugug/training-glossary/wiki/Compass) extension out of your project.

Comment: Andrey is correct, from the [Sass `@import` docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import): "Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain restrictions. It’s not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports."

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use variables in import paths as already mentioned.  What you *can* do is use the `-I` or `--load-path` option to specify a directory to search from.

```
sass --watch sass/:css/ --load-path ../../path/to/library/
```

Let's say you have a directory structure like this:

```
themes
    hotdog
        _variables.scss
    classic
        _variables.scss
styles.scss
```

Your styles.scss should have import paths that are relative to the provided load-path(s):

```
// note the import here doesn't contain themes, hotdog, or classic
@import "variables"; 

@debug $foo;
```

Your commands would look something like this:

```
# hotdog
sass styles.scss hotdog.css --load-path ./themes/hotdog/
# classic
sass styles.scss classic.css --load-path ./themes/classic/
```

See the [Sass options documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options) for more information.