# Webpack and Bootstrap with variable path

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

Migrating to Webpack I had some issues with import sass or css.

I have Bootstrap installed in my node_modules and inside my file structure I' trying to do this:

```
// folder scss
- vendor
   - bootstrap
   - pickadate
- views
- components
- base
```

Inside the bootstrap scss, I have the import for bootstrap files and since the path is big, I'm trying to use a variable to reuse:

```
$path: '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/';
@import '#{$path}variables';
@import '#{$path}grid';
@import '#{$path}responsive-utilities';
```

With the code above I'm getting this error:

```
Module build failed:
@import '#{$path}';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: #{$path}.
```

Anyone knows why?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [Import path using variable SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568179/import-path-using-variable-sass)

Interpolation in @import urls is not support.

Additionally, you could import like so:

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables';
```