# Is it possible to import dynamically path in SASS?

Tags: variables, import, sass

I would like to define 'path/var1.scss' or 'path/var2.scss' filename in my main.scss like a variable. 
After I would like to use(import) this variable in my main.scss .

```
//in the main.scss file

$myVariable = "path/var1.scss";

@import $myVariable;
```

Is it possible? How can achieve it?
Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import path using variable SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568179/import-path-using-variable-sass)

Answer (score -1):

In your main.scss, at the top, import your var.scss like this: `@import "<relative path to file>"` so it will look something like this: `@import "../app/scss/var.scss"` depending on where the file is situated in your project. Then, after it is imported, you can use the files as you need, for instance: `background-color: $pink`.