# Dinamically add scss file to difference projects, with one sass-project

Tags: sass, watch, compass

I have several projects and one sass-project

```
projectOne
    sass
        config.rb
        projectOne.scss
projectTwo
    sass
        config.rb
        projectTwo.scss
projectSass
    custom
        projectOne
        projectTwo
```

Example for variants below
All projects get sass from projectSass

How can i add to global projectSass dinamicly only one file, if i run `compass watch` in the project

1. May be add to project projectOne.scss with variable 
   $project: projectOne (where projectOne == dirname), then, `if $project`? But i can`t get dirname in sass. For this variant i wrote structure subfolders above
2. May be via config.rb? From structure with custom:projectOne:projectTwo. And add import only one, where projectOne==projectName==dirname
3. May be via gulp?
4. May be via compass compile. Example `compass compile -exclude=dir but -include=projectname.scss`

Answer (score 0):

It`s my solution via gulp.

```
gulp.task('compass', function () {
    var path = require("path");
    return gulp
        .src(['projectSass', '!projectSass/custom/', 'projectSass/custom/' + path.basename(__dirname) + '.scss'])
        .pipe($.compass({
            project: __dirname,
            watch: true,
            config_file: 'config.rb',
            css: path.basename(__dirname) + 'project/css',
            sass: '/media/sass',
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('project/css'))
});
```

with structure folders

```
projectSass
    custom
       projectOne.scss
       projectTwo.scss
```

May be anybody have more beautiful solution

**SECOND SOLUTION**

in config.rb

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
    def dir_name()
        project_name = Pathname.new(File.dirname(__FILE__)).basename.to_s
        Sass::Script::String.new(project_name)
    end
end
```

in scss we get string project_name
but not working

```
@import dir_name(); # impossible in sass now
```

possible, but not nice

```
if dir_name() == 'projectOne' {
    @include projectOne;
```

**THIRD SOLUTION**
I choice this solution

With `sass --watch --load-path`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34227039/2742948