# PhpStorm error "unexpected interpolation" when using interpolation on variable in @import within SCSS file

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I want to add a path prefix in an `@import` in my main `theme.scss` file but am getting the error `Unexpected interpolation`.

*(I am using [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) because the variable is in a string.)*

```
$path-prefix: "../Scss/";

// No error on this
.test::before {
  content: "#{$path-prefix}";
}

// But this produces and error
@import "#{$path-prefix}variables";
```

[image: Snapshot of the "unexpected interpolation" error in PhpStorm]

Comment: I had PhpStorm 2018.2.5 and just updated to to the most recent version 2018.3 and that did not help.

Comment: I can't make your code compile (tried both *sass* and *node-sass*) - is it valid? from SASS docs: `Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain restrictions. It's not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports. For example:

$family: unquote("Droid+Sans");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{$family}");

would compile to

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans");
`

Comment: I think you are right. An interpolated variable cannot be used in `@import`... I see someone else had the same trouble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600018/can-variables-be-used-in-import-statements-for-sass-files